# what is used in windows app on the place of Session?

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, c#-4.0, session

i am new to windows programming, as we use Store user's details in Session when user successfully logged into a web application and check the session in master page every time, if it will null then redirect the user to login page. I want to do the same thing in Windows application, i have created a login form: the code is written below:

```
private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        clsLogin obj = new clsLogin();
        DataTable dtLogin = obj.Login_Check(txtUserName.Text.Trim(), txtPassword.Text.Trim());
        if (dtLogin.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            if (dtLogin.Rows[0]["result"].ToString() == "3")
            {
                lblMessage.Text = "Password does not matched";
            }
            else
                if (dtLogin.Rows[0]["result"].ToString() == "2")
                {
                    lblMessage.Text = "User does not exists";
                }
                else
                {

                    Staff.Home home = new Staff.Home();
                    this.Hide();
                    home.Show();
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Now what i want to do is: store the user info some where and when user click on Log off then it will destroy that session and it will open the Login form.

i know it is a very silly question, as i am new to windows programming its tough for me, please help.

Comment: I'll give you a hint: use static variables and methods to store the logged in user.

Comment: This needs further clarification, I get what you're trying to ask in principle, but as there is no built in equivalent what is it you're trying to achieve?

Comment: @Clint as in web based app we used session or membership variables to store users info when he logged in to the application, and destroy this when he click on log out button in windows applicatio

i want to do the same thing here

Comment: @NicolasTyler i know C# very well but i am new to windows based application so please help me if you can

Comment: Well then just store the login details(Session guid and username) in a variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from the obvious issues with the code:

1. Direct access to rows by index
2. Login being done in the event handler directly

   - You should have separate login service and data access service

I would:

1. Create a login service that maintains the current logged in user details and performs the authentication itself.
2. Create a data access service that the login service can call to access the datastore

Then in your event handler you just need to call:

```
if (loginService.Authenticate(username, password))
{
   // Do your UI handling here
}
```

then the loginService will have a .CurrentUser property for example and you can go from there.

e.g.

```
public class LoginService
{
    private User _currentUser;
    public bool Authenticate(string username, string password)
    {
        if (_currentUser != null)
        {
            Logout();
        }
        else
        {
            var user = DataAccess.Get("users").SingleOrDefault(u => u.Username = username);
            if (user == null)
            {
                throw new Exception("No user with that username found");
            }

            if (password == user.Password)
            {
                _currentUser = user;
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    public User CurrentUser
    {
        get { return _user; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In a Web application it is supposed that there are multiple clients connected to the single server; you should use Session to distinguish between them and to pass data to each of them "there and back again". For a desktop application this problem does not exist at all - there is exactly one user and his data is all here: you do not need some special mechanism like Session for it. 
This means that you may use a number of different approaches to pass data from your form. In your example it seems more logical to pass data to your "home" form directly, either through constructor

```
else
{
    var userData = .... (txtUserName.Text);
    Staff.Home home = new Staff.Home(userData);
    this.Hide();
    home.Show();
}
```

or through a property

```
else
{
    var userData = .... (txtUserName.Text);
    Staff.Home home = new Staff.Home();
    home.UserData = userData;
    this.Hide();
    home.Show();
}
```

This is only an example, there are a lot alternatives - just think about this "single user, always on site" model.

Comment: then it means i need to pass the data from one form to another and so on...?

Comment: You do not have to (there are alternatives), but you can and it is usually a good enough solution.